# How to perform a conditional test within a Talend job?

Tags: talend

I am looking to trigger a series of processes, and I want to tell if each one succeeds or fails before starting the subsequent ones.

I am using tSSH (on Talend 6.4.1) to trigger a process and I only want the job to continue if it is a success. The tSSH "component" doesn't appear to fail if it receives a non-zero return code, so I have tried using an assert. However, even if the assert fails, it doesn't appear to prevent the component and subjob being "OK" which is a bit odd, so I can't use on-(component|subjob)-ok to link to the next job.

I don't seem to be able to find any conditional evaluation components which will allow me to stop the continuation of the job or subjob based on the evaluation result.

The only way I can find is to have

```
tSSH1 --IF globalMap.get("tSSH_1_EXIT_CODE").equals(0)--> tSSH2...
      --IF !globalMap.get("tSSH_1_EXIT_CODE").equals(0)--> (failure logging subjob)
```

which means coding the test twice with negation.

Am I missing something, or are there no such conditional components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put a if condition on tSSH component for success /failure using global variable of tSSH component i.e.

((String)globalMap.get("tSSH_1_STDERR")) and ((String)globalMap.get("tSSH_1_STDOUT")).

if condition you can check is :

if(((String)globalMap.get("tSSH_1_STDERR")) != null) than call error log
else call tSSH2.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I'm confused as to where you're suggesting I put this "if" test.

Comment: Right click on tSSH component and select runif and connect to next component. Now write the condition accordingly using global variable I suggested you